# Pair with a Bluetooth device over Terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, bluetooth

I am trying to connect and pair a Bluetooth device from the command line. I can do it over the GUI using the standard process but I am looking to automate the whole process.

I am looking for commands that can be executed in a shell script to connect to the Bluetooth device. Just like Linux has "hcitool", "pand" commands, I am trying to find equivalent commands for macOS.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 7):

`blueutil` (available via HomeBrew) is the answer. I just used it following the guidelines in [this blog post](https://trevorsullivan.net/2019/07/30/control-bluetooth-on-apple-macbook-pro-from-the-command-line/).

In my case, I had an iMac with macOS Catalina that had no trackpad paired. I was stuck at the "Send Apple Crash Analytics?" screen with no keyboard controls. Using SSH, I connected to the machine and used the following commands to pair and then connect the trackpad without access to the GUI. (First, I had to turn the trackpad into Discoverable mode. The default PIN for Apple pointer devices is `0000`.)

```
% blueutil --inquiry
address: d0-a6-xx-xx-xx-xx, not connected, not favourite, not paired, name: "-", recent access date: -
% blueutil --pair d0-a6-xx-xx-xx-xx
Type pin code (up to 16 characters) for "Cheshire, Josh’s Trackpad" (d0-a6-xx-xx-xx-xx) and press Enter: 0000
% blueutil --connect d0-a6-xx-xx-xx-xx
```

At that point, the trackpad worked.

Comment: `blueutil --recent` i run this option have a list but `blueutil --inquiry` as no new devices are avaiable.

Answer (score 4):

The tool [blueutil](https://github.com/toy/blueutil) uses private APIs from the IOBluetooth framework to interact with bluetooth devices. You are able to list recent devices using:

```
blueutil --recent
```

and connect to a specific device using:

```
blueutil --connect $device_adress
```

Answer (score 2):

This seems a little bit "hacky", but you can do this by using an oascript which emulates the GUI-interactions needed for connecting: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23018886/5269642

I couldn't really find any documented API's for bluetooth unfortunately, the oascript-approach was the best I could find/think of so far.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this:

https://github.com/lapfelix/BluetoothConnector

TL;DR

```
$ brew install bluetoothconnector

$ BluetoothConnector # gets the address of your connected devices

$ BluetoothConnector 00-00-00-00-00-00 --notify # toggles the connection
```

Replace the 00-00-00-00-00-00 with your MAC address